# GWT "big" Forms

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

I completed the StockWatcher basic gwt tutorial, and read several pages of documentation but I can't find the solution for a very simple thing.

What if my stock was a "real" object, such as an invoice, with dozens of fields to be entered by hand?b

I suppose I have to write a panel with many text boxes, and on the 'OK' button click, retrieve each textbox value in a awful way:

```
codeTb.getText();
year.getText();
customerTb.getText();
...
```

Then build a POJO-DTO and send through the RPC wire.

Really, isn't there a more simple way?

I think about a concept of "Form" in Gwt. Sorry, maybe I didn't find it in the doc, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT has what are called Editors. With Editors you can bind Widgets to a DTO and it's fields, so you don't have to do the getText or setText yourself. It's not totaly trivial to use, but you can find more details in the GWT documentation: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html

Comment: it's the right way, thank you. The documentation is actually non-trivial, don't you know about a simpler example? :)

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a FormPanel. Take a look here http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html

Comment: A FormPanel isn't going to help. While in HTML if you submit a form it will send all fields to the server, in GWT you want to copy the content of the fields in JavaScript on the client and that's not compatible with how a form works. In general you won't use FormPanel to submit content to the server, but do it via GWT RPC or the newer Request method.

Comment: Great! :) Can you tell me more about that "request method"?